# How to implement "delete all" for a Spring Roo Entity?

Tags: jpa, spring-roo, transactional

I'm trying to delete all database entries for a Spring Roo entity. When I look at `*_Roo_Entity.aj` it seems as if there is no "delete all" method. I tried to implement it myself (`Licences` is the name of the Roo entity. Don't mind the naming. It was reverese engineered from a database and may be changed later):

```
public static int Licences.deleteAll() {
    return entityManager().createQuery("delete from Licences o").executeUpdate();
}
```

It compiles just fine but when I call `Licences.deleteAll()` I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; 
nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query (NativeException)
```

Adding `@Transactional` doesn't make a difference.

What am I missing here?

Is this approach completely wrong and I need to implement it like this:

```
    public static void Licences.deleteAll() {
        for (Licences licence : findAllLicenceses()) {
            licence.remove();
        }
    }
```

This works, but is JPA smart enough to translate this into a `delete from licences` query or will it create `n` queries?

Answer (score 6):

@Transactional doesn't work on static function

change

```
public static int Licences.deleteAll() {
    return entityManager().createQuery("delete from Licences o").executeUpdate();
}
```

to

```
public int Licences.deleteAll() {
    return entityManager().createQuery("delete from Licences o").executeUpdate();
}
```

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5999

Bye

Comment: Thanks so much.. after hours of googling unable to find answer. Going thru all the answers giving rubbish documentation answers. nobody pointed as silly mistake as this. I had finally decided to scroll down to you answer. You saved me :) :) An Up-vote from :) :)

Answer (score 2):

JPA does not have a delete all functionality. <s>(even not with JQL!)</s>

At least there are only three ways:

- The loop, like you did
- A JPQL Query see: [JPQL Reference: 10.2.9. JPQL Bulk Update and Delete](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html)
- A native SQL Query, but this will cause many problems with Entity Manager caches!

BTW: It seams that you are using AspectJ to attach you delete method. - You can do this (even if I do not know, why not adding the static method direct to the Entity class), but **you must not touch the Roo generated aj files!**

Comment: I did indeed add the method to the Roo .aj files and found out rather quickly that this isn't advisable. I ended up adding the static method to the entity class. - The loop works for my purposes (very few rows) so I kept it. Otherwise a JPQL-Query might seem to be the best option.

Comment: @hvolkmer: there is the rumour, that Deleate by JPQL will not trigger the cascade delete action, but I don't know if this is correct. So pay attention to this, if you user delete cascade.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int Licences.deleteAll() {
    return new Licences().deleteAllTransactional();
}

@Transactional
private int Licences.deleteAllTransactional() {
    if (this.entityManager == null) this.entityManager = entityManager();
    return this.entityManager.createQuery("delete from Licences o").executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: its better if you add a description for your answer

Comment: the answer is as above. @Transactional is not supported in static methods